# How to call django.setup() in console_script?

Tags: python, django, python-import, freeze

The current django docs tell me this:

> django.setup() may only be called once.
>
> Therefore, avoid putting reusable application logic in standalone scripts so that you have to import from the script elsewhere in your application. If you can’t avoid that, put the call to django.setup() inside an if block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import django
    django.setup()
```

Source: [Calling django.setup() is required for “standalone” Django usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

I am using entry points in setup.py. This way I don't have `__name__ == '__main__'`.

## Question

How to ensure django.setup() gets only called once if you use [console_scripts](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point)?

Where should I put `django.setup()`?

## Background

The actual error I have: Django hangs. Here is the reason: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27176

I want to port my application to the current django version. Changing to a management command is not an option, since other (third party applications) rely on the existence of my console scripts.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Maybe also mention what you are trying to do as very often a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) might be the cleaner solution when doing something that needs the django environement.

Comment: @BernhardVallant I updated the question. Changing to management command is not an option.

Comment: The documentation you quote implies that the problem can be avoided by splitting the script that contains "reusable application logic" into two parts: a) script code which is not reusable and calls `django.setup()` b) the "reusable application logic" which can be imported by the script and anything else that needs it and which *does not* call `django.setup()`. Why can't you just do this?

Comment: @Louis yes, I could split the code into "script" and "reusable application logic". But this creates untestable code: AFAIK I can test the script except  by calling it via subprocess. This makes mocking impossible.

Comment: Any news for this?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev thank you for asking. I added my solution as an answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I love condition-less code, I use this solution. It's like in the django docs, but the ulgy `if __name__ == '__pain__'` gets avoided.

File with code:

```
# utils/do_good_stuff.py
# This file contains the code
# No `django.setup()` needed
# This code can be used by web apps and console scripts.

from otherlib import othermethod

def say_thank_you():
    ...
```

File for main:

```
# do_good_stuff_main.py
import django
django.setup()

def say_thank_you_main():
    from myapp import do_good_stuff
    return do_good_stuff()
```

setup.py:

```
    'console_scripts': [
        'say_thank_you=myapp.do_good_stuff_main:say_thank_you_main',
    ...
```

This is my current solution. Ffeeback welcome. Is there something to improve?

Comment: So basically your solution is to do exactly what I suggested in my comment on your question.

Comment: @Louis yes. Still one issue left: `do_good_stuff_main.py` would call `django.setup()` for the second time if it would get imported for testing.

Answer (score 8):

had the same problem (or something similar). I solved it by doing:

[Warning: dirty solution]

```
if not hasattr(django, 'apps'):
    django.setup()
```

this way it'll be called only once even if it's imported multiple times

Answer (score 7):

Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/#setup we can see what `django.setup` actually does.

> Configure the settings (this happens as a side effect of accessing the
>   first setting), configure logging and populate the app registry.
>   Set the thread-local urlresolvers script prefix if `set_prefix` is True.

So basically to ensure that setup was already done we can check if apps are ready and settings are configured

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings

if not apps.ready and not settings.configured:
    django.setup()
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the "if not ...". In other words, what happens if django.setup() gets called twice?

Comment: @guettli It will probably fail with `raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')`. Because it will try to configure settings again. But apps.populate should not have any problems because it does this `if self.ready: return`

Answer (score 2):

I have worked in two production CLI python packages with explicitly calling `django.setup()` in `console_scripts`.

The most important thing you should note is `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in `env` path.

You can set this value in shell script or even load default settings in your python script.

Here is example:

```
# setup.py
entry_points={
    'my-cli = mypackage.cli:main'
}
```

.

```
# cli.py
import logging
from os import environ as env


if not 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' in env:
    from mypackage import settings
    env.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', settings.__name__)


import django
django.setup()

# this line must be after django.setup() for logging configure
logger = logging.getLogger('mypackage')

def main():
    # to get configured settings
    from django.conf import settings

    # do stuffs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.2.5 (at least), the settings are configured on their import. `django.setup()` configures them because it imports them. The problem with calling `django.setup()` twice is that you'd be populating the apps specified in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` twice which can cause all sorts of problems.

The `if not apps.ready:` check is all you should use thus:

```
import django

if not apps.ready:
    django.setup()
```

Using `if not (apps.ready or settings.configured):` - is wrong because the settings may have been configured with an import statement elsewhere and the apps might still not have been populated so `django.setup()` might not get called when it is needed.

That said, if you know your standalone entry point (e.g. `main.py`) you can just call it there without the condition. The condition is only needed if there is a risk of actually running the script twice, perhaps by importing your standalone module into another standalone module so they both call django.setup. Importing a module multiple times will only run it once.